# MySQL - self join - Output to show pairs without duplicate names in a row and even also with the order reversed

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table showing a list of **Salespersons**  (snum, same, city).

1. Now I want to find all pairs of salespeoples who are from the same city.
2. Also to exclude combinations of salespeoples with themselves in a row.
3. as well as duplicate rows with the order reversed.

I use self join to find the solution for (1) and (2):

```
select  sa.sname A, s.sname B, s.city  
from salespeoples sa 
inner join salespeoples s 
on sa.city = s.city 
where (sa.sname != s.sname);
```

Output of above command is as follows :

[image]

But Still, I am getting duplicate entries if the order is reversed. How to remove this duplicate entry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `<` , not `!=`:

```
select  sa.sname A, s.sname B, s.city  
from salespeoples sa inner join
     salespeoples s 
     on sa.city = s.city 
where sa.sname < s.sname;
```

Comment: **Thank you!**  for the quick response. This is what I was looking for.